# Error during Quantum Espresso configuration

Tags: centos7, quantum-computing

During configuration QE and when writing `make all`, I got the following error:

```
From https://github.com/Reference-LAPACK/lapack
     * branch            12d825396fcef1e0a1b27be9f119f9e554621e55 -> FETCH_HEAD
    error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
            .appveyor.yml
            .travis.yml
    Please move or remove them before you can switch branches.
    Aborting
    make[1]: *** [liblapack] Error 1
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/rhome/Ragab/qe-7.1/install'
    make: *** [liblapack] Error 2
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do what it says: remove .appveyor.yml and .travis.yml